# Split a hex index into n pieces

Tags: mysql

I have a table with **primary keys in string** like `12a4...`, `c3af...`. I want to process them in parallel:

```
process_them(1,4) on machine 1
process_them(2,4) on machine 2
process_them(3,4) on machine 3
process_them(4,4) on machine 4
```

Doing the above must select **all rows** in the table, without machines coordinating with each other. The best idea I can come up with is to split them into 16 like:

```
select * from table where id like '1%'
...
select * from table where id like 'e%'
select * from table where id like 'f%'
```

Is there a better idea that allows me more splits like 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32 etc of the total rows?

Note: I am doing this to do nightly processing on user data and sending them notification. I am not editing anything on the DB itself. And we need to process thousands of users at a time, its cannot be split in a fine-grained manner as it wont be efficient that way.

Comment: If the machines have a incrementing system id, they could use that in a LIMIT clause. But that probably counts as "coordinating". IMHO to achieve something better than what you suggest they need to know something about their environment.

Comment: I think distributed database is best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Neat idea...

you can use an MD5 hash to distrubute the rows in a reasonable well distributed way quickly, consitently (There will never be a missed row) and without ddl changes.

```
*let n = number of desired partitions. Use the following sql to 
*let s = salt, expirementally chosen to provide the best distribution based on key allocation pattern.
SELECT *  FROM TABLE WHERE mod( cast( conv( md5( concat( s, Priamry_Key ) ), 16, 10), n ) = 0; 
SELECT *  FROM TABLE WHERE mod( cast( conv( md5( concat( s, Priamry_Key ) ), 16, 10), n ) = 1; 
...
...
SELECT *  FROM TABLE WHERE mod( cast( conv( md5( concat( s, Priamry_Key ) ), 16, 10), n ) = (n-1);
```

This is an approach I have seen implemented in production enviornments a few times with good results.

The SQL here isnt tested I make no gaurantee's on sytax.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be adding a `status` column to your table, with at least two states:

```
0 = pending
1 = *not* pending
```

Then each processing thread would be able "reserve" a small batch of rows to process them. The general workflow would be:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM queue WHERE status = 0 LIMIT 5 FOR UPDATE; -- load 5 pending items
-- if no pending item: terminate here
-- save this list of jobs in your application layer here
UPDATE queue SET status = 1 WHERE id IN (@id_list); -- list of id's from the previous step
COMMIT;
-- process your jobs here
-- loop
```

Depending on the actual processing time of your jobs, this approach may have too heavy an overhead to be satisfying. Increase the `LIMIT` in the first step so as to load more jobs at a time, to lower the relative overhead, at the cost of a possibly less balanced spread of jobs across processes.

Comment: We are not updating the data itself. And concurrent `select for update` like that would lock each other out till commit/abort. It wont be done in parallel.

Comment: No, in the worst case scenario, concurrent threads would be locked out just the time it takes for one thread to load jobs and update their statuses (`SELECT`, and `UPDATE`), i.e. a few milliseconds if the table is properly indexed. Notice the "process your jobs here" part is outside of the transaction. I am not sure adding and manipulating a new column for your operation only should be considered as "altering the data itself", but I understand this can be a no-go in some cases.